# Want to achieve drag drop functionality using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to achieve the functionality same as [this site](http://www.brighton.com/charmbuilder/create.php), when you select a bead it should drag from scroll pane div to another div having image of bracelet so that user can create his/her own bracelet. And he can be able to remove beads, reposition it on bracelet and resize it.

I have tried to achieve but got stuck at one point when I tried to drop the bead over a bracelet it gets does not append over it.

Here is my code

```
<section>
    <div class="thumbs">    
        <a href="#" class="ablah1"> 
            <img id="blah1" class="i2" src="C14mm300.png" width="100%" height="100px" style="padding:10px;"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ablah2"> 
            <img id="blah2" class="i3" src="C17mm415.png" width="100%" height="100px" style="padding:10px;"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ablah3"> 
            <img id="blah3" class="i4" src="C25mm525.png" width="100%" height="100px" style="padding:10px;"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ablah4"> 
            <img id="blah4" class="i5" src="C32mm580.png" width="100%" height="100px" style="padding:10px;"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ablah3"> 
            <img id="blah3" class="i4" src="C32mm660.png" width="100%" height="100px" style="padding:10px;"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ablah4"> 
            <img id="blah4" class="i5" src="c38mm710.png" width="100%" height="100px" style="padding:10px;"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="dvSource" style="visibility:hidden;width:600px;height:50px;overflow:scroll;">
        <img alt="" src="s1.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="s2.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src=" C14mm300.png" />
        <img alt="" src="C17mm415.png" />
        <img alt="" src="s3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="dvDest">
        <a href="#" class="ablah">
            <img id="blah" class="i1" src="" style="position:relative;top:50px;float:left;left:0px;width:150%;height:50px;"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#dvSource img").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        refreshPositions: true,

        drag: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
            var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
            if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
                alert(image + " dropped.");
            } else {
                alert(image + " not dropped.");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#dvDest").droppable({

        overflow: true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
                $("#dvDest").html("");
            }
            ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
            ui.draggable.css('position', 'absolute');
            $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6yyta3g7/

Please some one can help me sort it.

Comment: For future questions, please include your code. A fiddle is great, but if the the site went down your question would have been un-answerable.